# React web bottom half modal

Tags: reactjs, mobile, responsive-design, material-ui

I'm building a resposinve version of an app using React JS and I'm looking for a **bottom half** modal component. Like the one in [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal).
I'm also using material-ui, I'm not sure if I can make a change in the modal dialog to get the same result.

[image]

Comment: you're building a react-native application?

Comment: responsive react web app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the `Dialog` [styles](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/#css) with `makeStyles` utility from material-ui to achieve [that behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010951/how-can-i-use-css-media-for-responsive-with-makestyles-on-reactjs-material-ui), when the screen reach the `xs` breakpoint the responsive styles are applied.

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import "./styles.css";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      alignItems: "flex-end" // push the dialog to bottom
    }
  },
  paper: {
    // make the content full width
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      margin: 0,
      maxWidth: "100%",
      width: "100%"
    }
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const openDialog = () => setOpen(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button onClick={openDialog}>Open dialog</Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onEnter={console.log("Hey.")}
        classes={{ container: classes.root, paper: classes.paper }}
      >
        <DialogTitle>Hello CodeSandbox</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>Start editing to see some magic happen!</DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see it working here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-dialog-sample-forked-pjd64?file=/src/index.js:41-1162 (resize window to see how it changes)

Comment: Thanks @diedu, thats exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use **reactstrap** for it with the following **CSS**:

```
.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.modal.show .modal-dialog {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

working example [stackblitz with reactstrap here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-modal-issue-koj89c?file=style.css)

or using material-UI, use the following **css** (400px is width of div, which has 32px padding on both sides)... so 232px is half of this number and gives us centered div always:

```
.modalBody {
  left: calc(50% - 232px);
  bottom: 0;
}
```

following change in JS from **material-UI's** [Modal example](https://material-ui.com/components/modal/):

```
  const body = (
    <div className={`${classes.paper} modalBody`}>
      <h2 id="simple-modal-title">Text in a modal</h2>
      <p id="simple-modal-description">
        Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
      </p>
      <SimpleModal />
    </div>
  );
```

working example [on code-sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-jg0c6?file=/style.css:0-55)