# MUI JSS combine media queries without repetition

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a set of CSS styles that need to be applied to multiple media query rules. Is there any way to do this without repetition? Currently something like this appears to be the only jank way:

```
[theme.breakpoints.up('xl')]: {
  color: 'red',
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  border: '1px solid blue',
  fontSize: 17,
  marginTop: 3,
  padding: 7,
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirecton: 'column',
},
[theme.breakpoints.only('md')]: {
  color: 'red',
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  border: '1px solid blue',
  fontSize: 17,
  marginTop: 3,
  padding: 7,
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirecton: 'column',
},
[theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
  color: 'red',
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  border: '1px solid blue',
  fontSize: 17,
  marginTop: 3,
  padding: 7,
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirecton: 'column',
}
```

Comment: @RyanCogswell asking clarifying questions is usually helpful. but not every question is asking for a functional code sample. this question is (and always was) about avoiding repetition and imo focusing on the code sample missed the point entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that the `theme.breakpoints` methods don't do anything magical -- they are just convenience methods for producing media query strings.

For instance `theme.breakpoints.down('xs')` (when using the default breakpoint values) evaluates to `@media (max-width:599.95px)` and `theme.breakpoints.only('md')` evaluates to `@media (min-width:960px) and (max-width:1279.95px)`. You can find the Material-UI code within the [createBreakpoints function](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createBreakpoints.js#L6).

The next step is being aware of the syntax for achieving your objective within CSS (and JSS). [Commas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#logical_operators) can be used to do an "or" of multiple media query conditions, so the string you want to produce for the example in your question would be as follows:

```
@media (max-width:599.95px), (min-width:960px) and (max-width:1279.95px), (min-width:1920px)
```

To avoid hard-coding the breakpoint values, you can produce the above string by stringing together (with commas) the desired function calls and getting rid of the extraneous cases of `@media` since that should only occur once at the beginning.

Here's a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor: "purple",
    [`${theme.breakpoints.down("xs")},${theme.breakpoints
      .only("md")
      .replace("@media", "")},${theme.breakpoints
      .up("xl")
      .replace("@media", "")}`]: {
      color: "red",
      backgroundColor: "green",
      border: "1px solid blue",
      fontSize: 17,
      marginTop: 3,
      padding: 7,
      display: "flex",
      flexDirecton: "column"
    }
  }
}));
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Button className={classes.button} variant="contained">
      Hello World!
    </Button>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit media queries]

Related answer: [How can I use CSS @media for responsive with makeStyles on Reactjs Material UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010951/how-can-i-use-css-media-for-responsive-with-makestyles-on-reactjs-material-ui/61013569#61013569)

Comment: arg! i totally tried this but obviously did it wrong. thanks for taking the time and putting up with me.